# Custom message from abstractmethod

Tags: python-3.x, exception, abstract-class

I want to use `abc.abstractmethod` in my codebase. My goal is that when somebody forgets to implement a mandatory method, they should get an error that tells them they need to implement the mandatory method.

The default message from abstract methods is something like:

```
$ python3 abc_incomplete.py

Subclass: True
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "abc_incomplete.py", line 24, in <module>
    print('Instance:', isinstance(IncompleteImplementation(),
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class
IncompleteImplementation with abstract methods load
```

Which I don't find very helpful. Someone unfamiliar with abstract classes will probably get confused by this and need help. Is there a way I can specify a custom message, such as:

`Class IncompleteImplementation doesn't have a load method. This method is mandatory in all subclasses of MyABC.`

Comment: That default error seems fairly obvious to me - `IncompleteImplementation with abstract methods {}` is a pretty dead giveaway.

Comment: @osuka_ Okay, but the question is how to change it.